# How to apply a formula to cells in a given range?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that is the result of a query and can return an arbitrary number of result rows (the number of columns is fixed).

I am calculating the range that corresponds to the result set. This is working well. I use it to copy the result set into my sheet.

Now that I have the results copied to my sheet I want to add a column with a formula that works against the cells in the row. How to do this? The issue is that the number of rows is not fixed, how to have the formula apply to the rows that happen to be there.

Here is a sample sheet:

- `Result Set` is the output of the query
- `Report` is the sheet I made with a copy of the result set

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1moa-cQxcgvjqcHJUw_GTMbUQhqF9l4tAK75EwR5U-PE/edit?usp=sharing)

Column C is what I am trying to populate, the number of rows for Columns A and B will update each time I open the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way:

```
=arrayformula(if(A13:A<>"",A13:A&"="&B13:B,""))
```